# How do you do dependency injection for Elixir GenServer?

Tags: dependency-injection, elixir

I am building a GenServer in Elixir, let's say it's a simple Queue like this

```
defmodule Queue do
  use GenServer

  def start_link(name) do
    GenServer.start_link(__MODULE__, :ok, name: name)
  end

  def push(server, msg) do
    GenServer.call(server, {:subscribe, channel, last_id})
  end

  def pop(server) do
    GenServer.call(server, {:pop, channel, last_id})
  end

  # handlers here ...
end
```

For this queue, I wan to provide different storage backends, like

- PostgreSQL
- Redis
- In-memory
- File

So and so on. Here's the question, how can I do dependency injection with this GenServer? Ideally I want to create a Queue with different backend like this for database backend

```
{:ok, db_queue} = Queue.start_link(:DBQueue, db_process_pid)
```

and for redis may like this

```
{:ok, redis_queue} = Queue.start_link(:RedisQueue, redis_process_pid)
```

In this way, I can create the same queue server with different backend. What is the best practice for Elixir to do dependency injection for a GenServer?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you only want to store a pid, you can use the GenServer state to store it. You can then access it from the `handle_*` callback functions. For example, here's how the Queue would be like:

```
defmodule Queue do
  use GenServer

  def start_link(name, pid) do
    GenServer.start_link(__MODULE__, pid, name: name)
  end

  def init(pid), do: {:ok, pid}

  ...
end
```

You can now start it like you want to:

```
{:ok, db_queue} = Queue.start_link(:DBQueue, db_process_pid)
```

And then in your `handle_*` callbacks, access the state (which is just a pid in this case) from the last argument:

```
def handle_call({:subscribe, channel, last_id}, from, pid) do
  # use the pid and the message to construct a reply
  reply = ...
  {:reply, reply, pid}
end
```

If you want to store more things, like say a module as well, just change `pid` everywhere to a map like `%{pid: ..., module: ...}`. Any Erlang term can be used as the state.